# Changing theme outline color

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I created a pie chart using the Claro theme and want to change the outline color to transparent or just turn it off.  The default background color for Claro is a light gray which I wanted to change to transparent.  I was able to change the background color to transparent before setting the chart theme by using this code:

```
theme.chart.fill={color: "transparent"};
theme.plotarea.fill={color: "transparent"};
chart.setTheme(theme);
```

I am still left with a border around the chart that is light gray.  Any ideas on how to change this to transparent or turn it off??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the "stroke" color for the theme like this:

```
theme.chart.stroke = {color:"transparent"}
```

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hnBp/) in jsfiddle